# Why is the sfdx force:source:retrieve command not retrieving any field permissions?

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error

I'm trying to retrieve  field permissions for a specific profile, but when I run

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Profile:Admin`

I get no `<fieldPermissions>` in the profile xml file.

My package.xml file looks like this (if it even matters)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>     
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>    
    <types>
        <members>*</members>        
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>      
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
    </types> 
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StandardValueSet</name>
    </types>         
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>          
    <version>56.0</version>
</Package>
```

I expect to get profile field level access as set in the target org, e.g

```
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.AccountSource</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
```